# Replicate underwater / wave effect in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, effects

A musician in my country has these covers for his newest songs which all use some sort of wavy underwater effect.

Any ideas or pointers to how to achieve a similiar effect in Photoshop?

They look like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What has failed?  Hint: You could find [stock images like these](https://stock.adobe.com/uk/search/images?filters%5Bcontent_type%3Aphoto%5D=1&filters%5Bcontent_type%3Aillustration%5D=1&filters%5Bcontent_type%3Azip_vector%5D=1&filters%5Bcontent_type%3Aimage%5D=1&order=relevance&safe_search=1&price%5B%24%5D=1&search_type=usertyped&search_page=1&limit=100&k=water+wave+underwater&acp=&aco=water+wave+underwater&get_facets=0) and make a composite in Photoshop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Look for an underwater image like [this one](https://unsplash.com/photos/k7l9PFRbwy8) from unsplash.com

[image: underwater]

- Mask everything except the water

[image: Mask]

- Use another image, like [this one](https://unsplash.com/photos/sum0Apdexks) from unsplash.com

[image: boy]

- Put it under the *Water Layer*
- Duplicate it at the top of the *Water Layer* and use the same mask but change the mask levels reducing the highlights

[image]

- Duplicate the *Object Layer* in a new document and make a Duotone

[image: duotone]

- Transform this Duotone into an RGB image and duplicate the layer to the original file
- Change the blend mode, in this example to Hard Light

[image: hardlight]

- Add a masked *Bubble Layer* on top, Screen mode

  [image]

Comment: Some refraction would be nice. Spliting the guy into 3 pices for the 3 diferent zones.

Comment: Next lesson ‍